# Sometimes NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage returning bad request

Tags: .net, entity-framework, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-table-storage

I am using the **azure table and NLog (NLog.Extensions.AzureTableStorage)** to write SQL audit logs,
which is done by creating a **database interceptor in Entity framework** and it's working perfectly most of the time, but sometimes I am getting a bad request which can be observed from the application insights.

Below is the code used to write the Log

```
public class DBCommandInterceptor : DbCommandInterceptor
    {

        private readonly Logger _logger = LogManager.GetLogger("SQLAuditLog");

        public override void NonQueryExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<int> interceptionContext)
        {
            HandleCommandExecuting(command);
        }

        public override void ReaderExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<DbDataReader> interceptionContext)
        {
            HandleCommandExecuting(command);
        }

        public override void ScalarExecuting(DbCommand command, DbCommandInterceptionContext<object> interceptionContext)
        {
            HandleCommandExecuting(command);
        }

        private void HandleCommandExecuting(DbCommand command)
        {           
            LogEventInfo eventLog = new LogEventInfo(LogLevel.Trace,_logger.Name, command.CommandText);
            eventLog.Properties["Query"] = command.CommandText;
            eventLog.Message = $"{ command.CommandText} ";
            _logger.Log(eventLog);

        }
    }
```

What would be the reason for the bad request error?

Comment: Bad request (400 status code) error usually means invalid data. Can you share the data that is being stored when you're getting this error?

Comment: that data is not available from the application insight

Comment: Is there any way to see my failed payload?

Comment: Consider trying out https://www.nuget.org/packages/NLog.Extensions.AzureCosmosTable/ (Also supports Azure Table Storage). It uses the latest Azure-Storage-Library from Microsoft. See docs: https://github.com/JDetmar/NLog.Extensions.AzureStorage#table-configuration